# Android code not returning String when web service is called

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I am facing a problem calling the web service from my Android code. My [web service code](http://pastebin.com/EmMkZ84m) returns a string with a delimiter '#' in between. Now i need to make a code in Android that will call the web service , separate the delimiters such that the actual names are displayed using a check box for the user to select

Here is my Android code :

```
package com.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class TestApp extends Activity {
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/getData";




  private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getData";


    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/login2/Service1.asmx";
    TextView tv;

    boolean[] bln1=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

        call();

        String[] arr={""};
        boolean[] bln = {false, false, false};

       bln1 = new boolean[arr.length];


        new AlertDialog.Builder(TestApp.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setMultiChoiceItems(arr,
                bln,
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton,
                            boolean isChecked) {


                        if(isChecked){
                            bln1[whichButton] = true;
                        }
                        else{
                            bln1[whichButton] = false;
                        }
                    }
                })
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {


            }
        })
       .show();


    }




    public void call()
    {
        try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            //request.addProperty("passonString", "Hello Android");



            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();


            tv.setText(result.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tv.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `result.toString()` is the way to get your result string from a soap response. You have to access the right subvalue.

Comment: @ZeissS : the result object must contain my returned string "abc#bcd#" rite? I am having a doubt whether what should I write so that my returned string is stored and then used as checkbox values..Can u provide any solution ..Thanks a lot !! :-)

Comment: Try saving the result in a variable and use the debugger to check what your actual result is. I don't have any solution since I never used KSoap2.

Comment: Hey i tried that but when I run the code, i get a message saying "the application stopped expectedly" also btw can I write "arr" instead of result since I am using arr to get my checkbox items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insteand of casing to object `Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();` casting

```
  SoapPrimitive responsesData = (SoapPrimitive) envelopes.getResponse();
  String result = responsesData .toString();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I just want to know something .What will result contain ? Will it have the string I have passed i.e "abc#gfg#" ? If yes then how would I separate the delimiter and give the final string for the checkbox thing ?

Comment: what is your method ( `getData`) return type? is it JSON or other?

Comment: it is String ..see the web service code i have mentioned in my post

Comment: IF your return type is Sting (with this format), then you use spit method. see `String str = "one#two#three";
String[] temp;

String delimiter = "#";
temp = str.split(delimiter);
for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
System.out.println(temp[i]);`

Comment: spit method or split method ? Also should I create another function for doing it or can it be done inside the call method itself

Comment: hey ur above code should be written in the call method itself rite ?

Comment: This palce you want to set the name `tv.setText(result.toString());`. is it?.if it is yes then `tv.setText(temp[0]);`.Its depends on requiremnet. Where you want to set the result in that palce paste this one & modify according to your requiremnt

Comment: @NagkeeranPiraba let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2005/discussion-between-parth-90-and-nagkeeran-piraba)